# In pyspark rdd.mapPartitions(f), should f be a generator?

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, iterator, generator, yield

I have code like this:

```
def f(items):
  results = []
  for item in items:
    results.append(process(item))
  return results

rdd.mapPartitions(f)
```

But this requires all results to be stored in memory, instead of processed one row at time.

In regular spark I know you're supposed to do an "iterator-to-iterator" transform here (according to the "High Performance Spark" book). Can I achieve the same result in pyspark with a generator like this?

```
def f(items):
  results = []
  for item in items:
    yield(process(item))


rdd.mapPartitions(f)
```